# Rails and caching geodata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, geolocation, redis

I am developing an application for `Ruby on Rails` and I do not know how best to organize the storage of data.

From clients (not Rails app) data sent to the server (the `public key` (stored in the appropriate model Rails app), and `geodata` (longlat)). Sending frequency from 1 to 3 seconds (different for each client).

**Objective:** To arrange temporary storage, which reaches some time, the accumulated data will provide to Rails application (which will be searched model  from `public key` and the view of data).
[image]

The problem is that I do not know whether to keep those values ​​or not in a relational database (`postgresql`), because of what I can not find a more suitable tool.

I know about `Redis`, but I do not know how to get it set up and do commit the transaction in the database. If the best choice would be to abandon commits to the database, and limited to just cache, then there is the difficulty of obtaining the data from the Rails (need to get all the data, but they are obviously with different keys). Furthermore, after receipt of the data they should remain the same for subsequent connections available to the client.

Please help, I want a well-designed application, which would continue to develop and support brought only fun :)

I have: Ruby on Rails 4.2, Postgresql  9.3.5.

Comment: what kind of data are we talking about, do we need to persist it for long periods, or just caching it for performance and reducing requests to the api ? can this data be identified by a key?

Comment: No long-term storage is not necessary. The idea is this: to save the data array and the array pass Rals application. My question is how to do it correctly in terms of design. Is it possible to send the total transaction data into the database, which runs Rails application. Or is it better not to store data in RAM, and using the API handle of a Rails application directly to the repository.

Comment: can the same requests be called more than once? if so you can cache it with a timeout for example

Comment: It would be nice to run queries on the timer, this is what I want. But I'm not sure what Redis is capable of that.
Yet I wonder whether I act by binding to the preservation of such frequently updated data into the main database.

Comment: The trick would be checking if the data is saved in the cache or not, if yes serve from cache, if no fetch new data, it's easy because redis supports timeout natively

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to store my data: in the cache, or in a database. These are only needed for one operation for a short time (at the time of the timer itself, then they will be overwritten), but during this time for them may be a lot of requests.